# Count Function in Access SQL Query

Tags: mysql, ms-access

List the guests by name and the number of times each has reserved a room at one of our hotels. Arrange the list in order from most-frequent to least-frequent guest.

I'm keep getting aggregate function for Firstname and LastName

So Far i have this code

```
SELECT FirstName, LastName, Count(ResNum) AS TotalReservations
FROM RESERVATION, GUEST
Where GUEST.GuestNo = RESERVATION.GuestNo
ORDER BY RESERVATION.GuestNo
```

**And here is the link for the RelationShip Table**

[View Relationship Table](http://www.mediafire.com/download/7m4ciuxgbb4v8m8/Report1.pdf)   **<--- LINK**

Comment: You're lacking a `group by` clause. And Access' underlying SQL engine will require that any field not being aggregated be listed in the group by.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT FirstName, LastName, Count(ResNum) AS TotalReservations
FROM RESERVATION
INNER JOIN GUEST ON GUEST.GuestNo = RESERVATION.GuestNo
GROUP BY FirstName, LastName
ORDER BY COUNT(ResNum) DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT g.FirstName, g.LastName, Count(r.ResNum) AS TotalReservations
FROM RESERVATION AS r
INNER JOIN GUEST AS g ON g.GuestNo = r.GuestNo
GROUP BY g.FirstName, g.LastName
ORDER BY Count(r.ResNum) DESC
```